# Can't execute casperjs through python on mac

Tags: python, macos, casperjs

I'm pretty new to Mac, sorry if this is something very simple.

I can run my javascript file through terminal using command:

```
casperjs myfile.js
```

However, I want to execute this command through python script.

this is what i've got:

```
pathBefore = os.getcwd()
os.chdir("path/to/javascript/")
cmd_output = subprocess.check_output(["casperjs click_email_confirm_link.js"], shell = True)
os.chdir(pathBefore)
print cmd_output
```

which returns `/bin/sh: casperjs: command not found`

As you can see, changing the working dir doesn't work. 
I can't figure out how to make /bin/sh recognise casperjs, any help would be very appreciated

thanks

EDIT: this is how my code looks now

.bash_profile environment variable:

`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/phantomjs/2.1.1/bin/phantomjs`

.profile environment variable:

`export PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE="/usr/local/Cellar/phantomjs/2.1.1/bin/phantomjs"`

```
`try:
    CASPER ='/usr/local/bin/casperjs'
    SCRIPT = 'path/to/javascript/click_email_confirm_link.js'
    params = CASPER + ' ' + SCRIPT
    stdout_as_string = subprocess.check_output(params, shell=True)
    print stdout_as_string
except CalledProcessError as e:
    print e.output`
```

which returns error:

`Fatal: [Errno 2] No such file or directory; did you install phantomjs?`

Comment: Have you tried to specify the full path of casperjs executable?

Comment: Changed "casperjs" to "usr/local/Cellar/casperjs/1.1.3/bin/casperjs" and python returns this: "/bin/sh: ./usr/local/Cellar/casperjs/1.1.3/libexec/bin/casperjs: No such file or directory"

Comment: It looks like you forgot the leading slash. It should be `/usr/local/Cellar/casperjs/1.1.3/bin/casperjs`

Comment: Also, are you sure the path is correct? Whas does `which casperjs` return?

Comment: `which casperjs` returned `/usr/local/bin/casperjs` now my code looks like this: `cmd_output = subprocess.check_output(["/usr/local/bin/casperjs click_email_confirm_link.js"], shell = True)` but now I get error saying : `CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/local/bin/casperjs click_email_confirm_link.js']' returned non-zero exit status 1`

Comment: `subprocess.check_output` takes a list for a reason. Have you tried `subprocess.check_output(["/usr/local/bin/casperjs", "click_email_confirm_link.js"], shell = True)`?

Comment: With an exception of CalledProccessError I was able to run something (See last edit), now I get this error: "Fatal: [Errno 2] No such file or directory; did you install phantomjs? " I tried to add phantomjs environment variable to .bash_profile and .profile, still nothing. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my issue by typing these three lines in terminal:

`sudo ln -s /path/to/bin/phantomjs /usr/local/share/phantomjs
sudo ln -s /path/to/bin/phantomjs /usr/local/bin/phantomjs
sudo ln -s /path/to/bin/phantomjs /usr/bin/phantomjs`

and using python code:

```
commands = '''
pwd
cd ..
pwd
cd shared/scripts/javascript
pwd
/usr/local/Cellar/casperjs/1.1.3/libexec/bin/casperjs click_email_confirm_link.js
''' 

process = subprocess.Popen('/bin/bash', stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = process.communicate(commands.encode('utf-8'))
print(out.decode('utf-8'))
```

also following files were edited like this:

vi .bash_profile

`export PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/Cellar/phantomjs/2.1.1/bin/phantomjs
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/phantomjs/2.1.1/bin/phantomjs`

vi .bashrc + source .bashrc

`export PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/Cellar/phantomjs/2.1.1/bin/phantomjs
export PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/phantomjs/2.1.1/bin:$PATH"`

vi .profile

`export PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/Cellar/phantomjs/2.1.1/bin/phantomjs
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/phantomjs/2.1.1/bin/phantomjs"`